# How do I get the value of a button element when submitted with PHP?

Tags: php

With `<input type="submit">` it's easy enough, it's just the value attribute. But for a `<button>Value</button>` the value goes in the middle (this allowed me to have an icon in the button label which was important).

How do I get that in PHP? If my button looks like `<button type="submit">Text <i class="icon-remove"></i></button>` do I include the `<i></i>` part?

Comment: assign a name to that button using name="value" and then access it.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<button name="name_of_button" value="some_value">Some Value</button>
```

assuming your form is `POST`ed the value is then used like `$_POST['name_of_button']`

Answer (score 1):

Just give your button element a name and value with the data you want passed.

```
<button type="submit" name="button" value="whatever">Text <i class="icon-remove"></i></button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your form use method POST:

```
<form method="POST" action="">
```

You could define your button like that:

```
<button value="value_button" type="submit" name="name_button">Submit</button>
```

And get his value like that:

```
$valueButton = $_POST['name_button'];
```